# Anaconda not finding my packages installed with `pip`

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm new to Anaconda version of Python, and already I'm running into unpleasant problems.

I installed Anaconda per [the instructions here](http://continuum.io/downloads), and it worked like charm, with all the included packages imported properly when demanded. Then I went on to install some extra packages which Anaconda did not included in the first place with `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip install BeautifulSoup mrjob pattern
```

The installations seems to be perfect, but when I try to import them in ipython, things get frustrating:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:47:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import BeautifulSoup
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-aa1e12a76f5e> in <module>()
----> 1 import BeautifulSoup

ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import mrjob
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6ea1b9bda48b> in <module>()
----> 1 import mrjob

ImportError: No module named mrjob

In [3]: import pattern
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4b662941bac1> in <module>()
----> 1 import pattern

ImportError: No module named pattern

In [4]:
```

Funny thing is, these packages can be very well imported when I'm not running the Anaconda bundle of python, after removing

```bsh
# added by Anaconda 1.8.0 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

from my `.bashrc`:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import mrjob

In [3]: import pattern

In [4]:
```

Did I miss anything during any of these installations that I ran? Should I manually link these packages to Anaconda so that it knows where to find them?

Comment: What does `which pip` output? Does `/home/username/anaconda/bin` contain `pip`? What about `easy_install`?

Comment: `which pip` outputs `/usr/bin/pip` and `~/anaconda/bin/` does contain `pip`. `easy_install` behaves just about the same.

Comment: does that mean I should be using `~/anaconda/bin/pip` instead of the system `pip`?

Comment: Yes; the system `pip` will probably install into a place Anaconda won't look. If Anaconda was in your path, your shell should have resolved `pip` as the one in `anaconda/bin`, but it appears that didn't happen.

Comment: Ah great, thanks! Now BeautifulSoup is very smoothly installed. But both the binaries of `pip` and `easy_install` in `~/anaconda/bin/` failed to download the other two packages, saying `Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse($package)`, which did not happen when I was using their system counterpart. Mind helping me figure out what's happening there?

Comment: Sure, but ask a new question.

Comment: hah, you know what? the problem solved itself after I rebooted my system. now all is good. thanks!

Comment: Something you need to run `hash -r` after installing something to update the hashes of your `PATH`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the comments, it was determined that the `pip` in use was `/usr/bin/pip`; in other words, the system `pip`. The system `pip` will install into the system `site-packages`, not Anaconda's `site-packages`.

The solution is to make sure you're using Anaconda's `pip` when installing packages for use with Anaconda.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize you could use `pip` to install packages into a `conda` environment.

Comment: And on windows Anaconda's pip is in the Anaconda/script directory

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, conda for Python 3.  My conda pip was in ~/anaconda3/bin/pip.  I made an alias in my ~/.bashrc like `alias condapip=~/anaconda3/bin/pip` so that I can run `sudo condapip install somepackage`